# How to call a web request before deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, json

Attempting to get a web request before I attempt to deserilize my url unfortunately none of the conventional methods for making web requests work.

```
public WeatherModel GetWeather(string url)
    {
            WeatherModel WeatherData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<WeatherModel>(url);
            return WeatherData;
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a HTTP request to the URL and parse the response data. You cannot simply deserialize the URL.

Use `HttpClient` class to send HTTP requests. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Please refer to [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) to see how to make HTTP requests using `HttpClient`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Unfortunately I'm using MSV 2008, is there an elegant solution for ASP 2.0?

Comment: You can use `HttpWebRequest` class in .NET 3.5. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx